# iOS NSURLConnection: How to simulate 500 and 404 error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I am working on an iOS which connects to a RESTFUL Web Service for consuming data. I am handling the error scenarios in `connection: didFailWithError:` delegate method.

Recently I came to know that, I need to handle few errors in `connection: didReceiveResponse:` delegate method also. Because, errors like 500 internal error and 400, 404 gets notified in `connection: didReceiveResponse:`.

But, one concern is **I don't know how to test these scenarios**. How do I reproduce the 500 or 400 specific errors? Any suggestion on this will help me a lot!!

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this website to call for every status code you might (probably) need http://httpstat.us/

examples:
[400](http://httpstat.us/400)
[500](http://httpstat.us/500)

Format of the response

```
HTTP/1.1 {status code} {status description}
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: {something}
{any custom response headers}

{status code} {status description}
{list of any custom response headers we added}
```

Comment: This site just displays a string. So, when we encounter these errors in NSURLConnection, will the response be a normal string message or in any other format?

Comment: it doesnt only shows a string it returns a status code in HTTP as well as a string for you to see

Comment: Ok!! Can you please look at above answer which Mutawe posted. I asked a question in the comments there. Any help on that?

Comment: @RashmiRanjanmallick Answered please mark as correct and upvote if I helped you.

Comment: Sure. Thanks. I will do it.